# old scifi movie about a traveler who comes to earth

Tags: story-identification, movie

This is a 70s or 80s, at the most early 90s movie. I don't remember much of it. The main character (male) is an alien (looks human) or time traveler or some interdimensional traveler.

I don't know how he ends up on earth. There is this tiny ball-like robot with AI that helps him, or maybe it was a glowing light ball or something. A bunch of kids help this guy out & hide him in their garage or shed or something. Also this guy is trying to escape some people from where ever he is from. He has a radio which he uses to stop these people from crossing over from their dimension/timeline/whatever. The radio interferes with the portal/event horizon which is a fuzzy gateway and stops the people who are trying to get him.

Anyone have any idea what this movie is?

Comment: I recognize it, but can't think of the title.  I'll see what I can dig up.

Comment: First thing that came to mind with the "ball like robot" was [Hard Time on Planet Earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_Time_on_Planet_Earth) but it doesn't match the other points.

Comment: I'm *almost* certain I've seen this. I'm wracking my head like crazy right now!

Comment: Did the alien wear a silver suit for much of the movie?  Was it American, British, other?

Answer (score 6):

Since your question contains a lot of "or something"s, perhaps you're thinking of  [Starman](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088172/). He takes human form and has 7 small spheres that are 'magical', or perhaps AIs, which he uses to help people. He uses the first one to send a message 'home'. He's trying to get to a location where he can be picked up by his alien bretheren with the help of a woman. The 'bad guys' aren't aliens, it's the US government trying to capture him.

Better plot summary [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starman_%28film%29).